# Entity Framework saves data but cannot insert new data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to learn EF. Project is copy of walkthrough (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx)

For testing I have added some data using SSMS and can update that data but cannot insert new row from my app.

This is my code for load data

```
_context = new winproContext();
var query = _context.Customers;
this.customerBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Anyone knows why i cannot insert new?

Comment: Please post the code where you insert a new row.

Comment: Maybe posting your code would help with divining of your problem.

Comment: Given that he's using a `BindingSource`, my suspicion is that he's binding to a grid (or something similar) and adding a row within that control's ordinary capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a copy of your data source (the table) by calling `ToList()`. While I wouldn't ordinarily recommend binding directly to a table in a context like that, if you remove the call to `ToList()` it should work as expected once you call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: @wdosanjos thanks. That walkthrough don't have code for insert !             `var customer = new Customer { CustomerName = "test" };
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
            _context.SaveChanges();` work for me. Thanks all for comments